# Spark window function, create a rank column depending on values in dataset

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For a dataset, how could I use a window function to split the rows into logical parts using a value from one of the columns?

For ex. for the given example `title` = `Erev Rosh Hashana`

The transformation would produce from this:

```
+----------+-------------------------+--------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|date      |title                    |category|subcat|memo                                                                            |
+----------+-------------------------+--------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2018-01-31|Tu BiShvat               |holiday |minor |New Year for Trees                                                              |
|2018-02-28|Erev Purim               |holiday |major |Purim is one of the most joyous and fun holidays on the Jewish calendar         |
|2018-03-01|Purim                    |holiday |major |Purim is one of the most joyous and fun holidays on the Jewish calendar         |
|2018-03-02|Shushan Purim            |holiday |minor |Purim celebrated in Jerusalem and walled cities                                 |
|2018-03-30|Erev Pesach              |holiday |null  |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2018-03-31|Pesach I                 |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2018-04-01|Pesach II                |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2018-04-02|Pesach III (CH''M)       |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2018-04-03|Pesach IV (CH''M)        |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2018-04-04|Pesach V (CH''M)         |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2018-04-05|Pesach VI (CH''M)        |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2018-04-06|Pesach VII               |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2018-04-07|Pesach VIII              |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2018-04-12|Yom HaShoah              |holiday |modern|Holocaust Memorial Day                                                          |
|2018-04-18|Yom HaZikaron            |holiday |modern|Israeli Memorial Day                                                            |
|2018-04-19|Yom HaAtzma'ut           |holiday |modern|Israeli Independence Day                                                        |
|2018-04-29|Pesach Sheni             |holiday |minor |Second Passover, one month after Passover                                       |
|2018-05-03|Lag BaOmer               |holiday |minor |33rd day of counting the Omer                                                   |
|2018-05-13|Yom Yerushalayim         |holiday |modern|Jerusalem Day                                                                   |
|2018-05-19|Erev Shavuot             |holiday |null  |Festival of Weeks, commemorates the giving of the Torah at Mount Sinai          |
|2018-05-20|Shavuot I                |holiday |major |Festival of Weeks, commemorates the giving of the Torah at Mount Sinai          |
|2018-05-21|Shavuot II               |holiday |major |Festival of Weeks, commemorates the giving of the Torah at Mount Sinai          |
|2018-07-21|Erev Tish'a B'Av         |holiday |major |The Ninth of Av, fast commemorating the destruction of the two Temples          |
|2018-07-22|Tish'a B'Av              |holiday |major |The Ninth of Av, fast commemorating the destruction of the two Temples          |
|2018-07-27|Tu B'Av                  |holiday |minor |minor Jewish holiday of love, observed on the 15th day of the Hebrew month of Av|
|2018-09-01|Leil Selichot            |holiday |minor |Prayers for forgiveness in preparation for the High Holidays                    |
|2018-09-09|Erev Rosh Hashana        |holiday |null  |The Jewish New Year                                                             |
|2018-09-10|Rosh Hashana 5779        |holiday |null  |The Jewish New Year                                                             |
|2018-09-11|Rosh Hashana II          |holiday |major |The Jewish New Year                                                             |
|2018-09-18|Erev Yom Kippur          |holiday |null  |Day of Atonement                                                                |
|2018-09-19|Yom Kippur               |holiday |major |Day of Atonement                                                                |
|2018-09-23|Erev Sukkot              |holiday |null  |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2018-09-24|Sukkot I                 |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2018-09-25|Sukkot II                |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2018-09-26|Sukkot III (CH''M)       |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2018-09-27|Sukkot IV (CH''M)        |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2018-09-28|Sukkot V (CH''M)         |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2018-09-29|Sukkot VI (CH''M)        |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2018-09-30|Sukkot VII (Hoshana Raba)|holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2018-10-01|Shmini Atzeret           |holiday |major |Eighth Day of Assembly                                                          |
|2018-10-02|Simchat Torah            |holiday |major |Day of Celebrating the Torah                                                    |
|2018-10-16|Yom HaAliyah             |holiday |modern|Recognizes Aliyah, immigration to the Jewish State of Israel                    |
|2018-11-07|Sigd                     |holiday |modern|Ethiopian Jewish holiday occurring 50 days after Yom Kippur                     |
|2018-12-02|Chanukah: 1 Candle       |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2018-12-03|Chanukah: 2 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2018-12-04|Chanukah: 3 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2018-12-05|Chanukah: 4 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2018-12-06|Chanukah: 5 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2018-12-07|Chanukah: 6 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2018-12-08|Chanukah: 7 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2018-12-09|Chanukah: 8 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2018-12-10|Chanukah: 8th Day        |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2019-01-21|Tu BiShvat               |holiday |minor |New Year for Trees                                                              |
|2019-02-19|Purim Katan              |holiday |minor |Minor Purim celebration during Adar I on leap years                             |
|2019-03-20|Erev Purim               |holiday |major |Purim is one of the most joyous and fun holidays on the Jewish calendar         |
|2019-03-21|Purim                    |holiday |major |Purim is one of the most joyous and fun holidays on the Jewish calendar         |
|2019-03-22|Shushan Purim            |holiday |minor |Purim celebrated in Jerusalem and walled cities                                 |
|2019-04-19|Erev Pesach              |holiday |null  |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2019-04-20|Pesach I                 |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2019-04-21|Pesach II                |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2019-04-22|Pesach III (CH''M)       |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2019-04-23|Pesach IV (CH''M)        |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2019-04-24|Pesach V (CH''M)         |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2019-04-25|Pesach VI (CH''M)        |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2019-04-26|Pesach VII               |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2019-04-27|Pesach VIII              |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2019-05-02|Yom HaShoah              |holiday |modern|Holocaust Memorial Day                                                          |
|2019-05-08|Yom HaZikaron            |holiday |modern|Israeli Memorial Day                                                            |
|2019-05-09|Yom HaAtzma'ut           |holiday |modern|Israeli Independence Day                                                        |
|2019-05-19|Pesach Sheni             |holiday |minor |Second Passover, one month after Passover                                       |
|2019-05-23|Lag BaOmer               |holiday |minor |33rd day of counting the Omer                                                   |
|2019-06-02|Yom Yerushalayim         |holiday |modern|Jerusalem Day                                                                   |
|2019-06-08|Erev Shavuot             |holiday |null  |Festival of Weeks, commemorates the giving of the Torah at Mount Sinai          |
|2019-06-09|Shavuot I                |holiday |major |Festival of Weeks, commemorates the giving of the Torah at Mount Sinai          |
|2019-06-10|Shavuot II               |holiday |major |Festival of Weeks, commemorates the giving of the Torah at Mount Sinai          |
|2019-08-10|Erev Tish'a B'Av         |holiday |major |The Ninth of Av, fast commemorating the destruction of the two Temples          |
|2019-08-11|Tish'a B'Av              |holiday |major |The Ninth of Av, fast commemorating the destruction of the two Temples          |
|2019-08-16|Tu B'Av                  |holiday |minor |minor Jewish holiday of love, observed on the 15th day of the Hebrew month of Av|
|2019-09-21|Leil Selichot            |holiday |minor |Prayers for forgiveness in preparation for the High Holidays                    |
|2019-09-29|Erev Rosh Hashana        |holiday |null  |The Jewish New Year                                                             |
|2019-09-30|Rosh Hashana 5780        |holiday |null  |The Jewish New Year                                                             |
|2019-10-01|Rosh Hashana II          |holiday |major |The Jewish New Year                                                             |
|2019-10-08|Erev Yom Kippur          |holiday |null  |Day of Atonement                                                                |
|2019-10-09|Yom Kippur               |holiday |major |Day of Atonement                                                                |
|2019-10-13|Erev Sukkot              |holiday |null  |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2019-10-14|Sukkot I                 |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2019-10-15|Sukkot II                |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2019-10-16|Sukkot III (CH''M)       |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2019-10-17|Sukkot IV (CH''M)        |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2019-10-18|Sukkot V (CH''M)         |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2019-10-19|Sukkot VI (CH''M)        |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2019-10-20|Sukkot VII (Hoshana Raba)|holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2019-10-21|Shmini Atzeret           |holiday |major |Eighth Day of Assembly                                                          |
|2019-10-22|Simchat Torah            |holiday |major |Day of Celebrating the Torah                                                    |
|2019-11-05|Yom HaAliyah             |holiday |modern|Recognizes Aliyah, immigration to the Jewish State of Israel                    |
|2019-11-27|Sigd                     |holiday |modern|Ethiopian Jewish holiday occurring 50 days after Yom Kippur                     |
|2019-12-22|Chanukah: 1 Candle       |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2019-12-23|Chanukah: 2 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2019-12-24|Chanukah: 3 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2019-12-25|Chanukah: 4 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2019-12-26|Chanukah: 5 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2019-12-27|Chanukah: 6 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2019-12-28|Chanukah: 7 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2019-12-29|Chanukah: 8 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2019-12-30|Chanukah: 8th Day        |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
+----------+-------------------------+--------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The following:

```
+----+----------+-------------------------+--------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|rank|date      |title                    |category|subcat|memo                                                                            |
+----+----------+-------------------------+--------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1   |2018-01-31|Tu BiShvat               |holiday |minor |New Year for Trees                                                              |
|1   |2018-02-28|Erev Purim               |holiday |major |Purim is one of the most joyous and fun holidays on the Jewish calendar         |
|1   |2018-03-01|Purim                    |holiday |major |Purim is one of the most joyous and fun holidays on the Jewish calendar         |
|1   |2018-03-02|Shushan Purim            |holiday |minor |Purim celebrated in Jerusalem and walled cities                                 |
|1   |2018-03-30|Erev Pesach              |holiday |null  |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|1   |2018-03-31|Pesach I                 |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|1   |2018-04-01|Pesach II                |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|1   |2018-04-02|Pesach III (CH''M)       |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|1   |2018-04-03|Pesach IV (CH''M)        |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|1   |2018-04-04|Pesach V (CH''M)         |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|1   |2018-04-05|Pesach VI (CH''M)        |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|1   |2018-04-06|Pesach VII               |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|1   |2018-04-07|Pesach VIII              |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|1   |2018-04-12|Yom HaShoah              |holiday |modern|Holocaust Memorial Day                                                          |
|1   |2018-04-18|Yom HaZikaron            |holiday |modern|Israeli Memorial Day                                                            |
|1   |2018-04-19|Yom HaAtzma'ut           |holiday |modern|Israeli Independence Day                                                        |
|1   |2018-04-29|Pesach Sheni             |holiday |minor |Second Passover, one month after Passover                                       |
|1   |2018-05-03|Lag BaOmer               |holiday |minor |33rd day of counting the Omer                                                   |
|1   |2018-05-13|Yom Yerushalayim         |holiday |modern|Jerusalem Day                                                                   |
|1   |2018-05-19|Erev Shavuot             |holiday |null  |Festival of Weeks, commemorates the giving of the Torah at Mount Sinai          |
|1   |2018-05-20|Shavuot I                |holiday |major |Festival of Weeks, commemorates the giving of the Torah at Mount Sinai          |
|1   |2018-05-21|Shavuot II               |holiday |major |Festival of Weeks, commemorates the giving of the Torah at Mount Sinai          |
|1   |2018-07-21|Erev Tish'a B'Av         |holiday |major |The Ninth of Av, fast commemorating the destruction of the two Temples          |
|1   |2018-07-22|Tish'a B'Av              |holiday |major |The Ninth of Av, fast commemorating the destruction of the two Temples          |
|1   |2018-07-27|Tu B'Av                  |holiday |minor |minor Jewish holiday of love, observed on the 15th day of the Hebrew month of Av|
|1   |2018-09-01|Leil Selichot            |holiday |minor |Prayers for forgiveness in preparation for the High Holidays                    |
|2   |2018-09-09|Erev Rosh Hashana        |holiday |null  |The Jewish New Year                                                             |
|2   |2018-09-10|Rosh Hashana 5779        |holiday |null  |The Jewish New Year                                                             |
|2   |2018-09-11|Rosh Hashana II          |holiday |major |The Jewish New Year                                                             |
|2   |2018-09-18|Erev Yom Kippur          |holiday |null  |Day of Atonement                                                                |
|2   |2018-09-19|Yom Kippur               |holiday |major |Day of Atonement                                                                |
|2   |2018-09-23|Erev Sukkot              |holiday |null  |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2   |2018-09-24|Sukkot I                 |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2   |2018-09-25|Sukkot II                |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2   |2018-09-26|Sukkot III (CH''M)       |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2   |2018-09-27|Sukkot IV (CH''M)        |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2   |2018-09-28|Sukkot V (CH''M)         |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2   |2018-09-29|Sukkot VI (CH''M)        |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2   |2018-09-30|Sukkot VII (Hoshana Raba)|holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|2   |2018-10-01|Shmini Atzeret           |holiday |major |Eighth Day of Assembly                                                          |
|2   |2018-10-02|Simchat Torah            |holiday |major |Day of Celebrating the Torah                                                    |
|2   |2018-10-16|Yom HaAliyah             |holiday |modern|Recognizes Aliyah, immigration to the Jewish State of Israel                    |
|2   |2018-11-07|Sigd                     |holiday |modern|Ethiopian Jewish holiday occurring 50 days after Yom Kippur                     |
|2   |2018-12-02|Chanukah: 1 Candle       |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2   |2018-12-03|Chanukah: 2 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2   |2018-12-04|Chanukah: 3 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2   |2018-12-05|Chanukah: 4 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2   |2018-12-06|Chanukah: 5 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2   |2018-12-07|Chanukah: 6 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2   |2018-12-08|Chanukah: 7 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2   |2018-12-09|Chanukah: 8 Candles      |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2   |2018-12-10|Chanukah: 8th Day        |holiday |major |The Jewish festival of rededication, also known as the Festival of Lights       |
|2   |2019-01-21|Tu BiShvat               |holiday |minor |New Year for Trees                                                              |
|2   |2019-02-19|Purim Katan              |holiday |minor |Minor Purim celebration during Adar I on leap years                             |
|2   |2019-03-20|Erev Purim               |holiday |major |Purim is one of the most joyous and fun holidays on the Jewish calendar         |
|2   |2019-03-21|Purim                    |holiday |major |Purim is one of the most joyous and fun holidays on the Jewish calendar         |
|2   |2019-03-22|Shushan Purim            |holiday |minor |Purim celebrated in Jerusalem and walled cities                                 |
|2   |2019-04-19|Erev Pesach              |holiday |null  |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2   |2019-04-20|Pesach I                 |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2   |2019-04-21|Pesach II                |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2   |2019-04-22|Pesach III (CH''M)       |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2   |2019-04-23|Pesach IV (CH''M)        |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2   |2019-04-24|Pesach V (CH''M)         |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2   |2019-04-25|Pesach VI (CH''M)        |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2   |2019-04-26|Pesach VII               |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2   |2019-04-27|Pesach VIII              |holiday |major |Passover, the Feast of Unleavened Bread                                         |
|2   |2019-05-02|Yom HaShoah              |holiday |modern|Holocaust Memorial Day                                                          |
|2   |2019-05-08|Yom HaZikaron            |holiday |modern|Israeli Memorial Day                                                            |
|2   |2019-05-09|Yom HaAtzma'ut           |holiday |modern|Israeli Independence Day                                                        |
|2   |2019-05-19|Pesach Sheni             |holiday |minor |Second Passover, one month after Passover                                       |
|2   |2019-05-23|Lag BaOmer               |holiday |minor |33rd day of counting the Omer                                                   |
|2   |2019-06-02|Yom Yerushalayim         |holiday |modern|Jerusalem Day                                                                   |
|2   |2019-06-08|Erev Shavuot             |holiday |null  |Festival of Weeks, commemorates the giving of the Torah at Mount Sinai          |
|2   |2019-06-09|Shavuot I                |holiday |major |Festival of Weeks, commemorates the giving of the Torah at Mount Sinai          |
|2   |2019-06-10|Shavuot II               |holiday |major |Festival of Weeks, commemorates the giving of the Torah at Mount Sinai          |
|2   |2019-08-10|Erev Tish'a B'Av         |holiday |major |The Ninth of Av, fast commemorating the destruction of the two Temples          |
|2   |2019-08-11|Tish'a B'Av              |holiday |major |The Ninth of Av, fast commemorating the destruction of the two Temples          |
|2   |2019-08-16|Tu B'Av                  |holiday |minor |minor Jewish holiday of love, observed on the 15th day of the Hebrew month of Av|
|2   |2019-09-21|Leil Selichot            |holiday |minor |Prayers for forgiveness in preparation for the High Holidays                    |
|3   |2019-09-29|Erev Rosh Hashana        |holiday |null  |The Jewish New Year                                                             |
|3   |2019-09-30|Rosh Hashana 5780        |holiday |null  |The Jewish New Year                                                             |
|3   |2019-10-01|Rosh Hashana II          |holiday |major |The Jewish New Year                                                             |
|3   |2019-10-08|Erev Yom Kippur          |holiday |null  |Day of Atonement                                                                |
|3   |2019-10-09|Yom Kippur               |holiday |major |Day of Atonement                                                                |
|3   |2019-10-13|Erev Sukkot              |holiday |null  |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|3   |2019-10-14|Sukkot I                 |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|3   |2019-10-15|Sukkot II                |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|3   |2019-10-16|Sukkot III (CH''M)       |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|3   |2019-10-17|Sukkot IV (CH''M)        |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|3   |2019-10-18|Sukkot V (CH''M)         |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|3   |2019-10-19|Sukkot VI (CH''M)        |holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|3   |2019-10-20|Sukkot VII (Hoshana Raba)|holiday |major |Feast of Tabernacles                                                            |
|3   |2019-10-21|Shmini Atzeret           |holiday |major |Eighth Day of Assembly                                                          |
|3   |2019-10-22|Simchat Torah            |holiday |major |Day of Celebrating the Torah                                                    |
...
+----+----------+-------------------------+--------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new column that contains a 1 where `title` equals "Erev Rosh Hashana" and 0 otherwise. Then compute the cumsum of that column ordered by the date. Finally, remove the temporary column.

This can be done as follows:

```py
w = Window.orderBy("date")
df.withColumn("hit", when(df["title"] == "Erev Rosh Hashana", 1).otherwise(0))\
  .withColumn("rank", sum("hit").over(w) + 1)
  .drop("hit")
```

Added `+1` to the cumsum for the `rank` to start at 1.

---

Note that this can be slow for large dataframes. It would be preferable to have a column to partition by for the window operation, i.e. to add `partitionBy("col")`. However, this would not give the wanted output here.

Comment: That's a very cool hack, where can I learn more of these? Are there books or courses or website that teach working with window functions and general data processing using SQL with use cases ? Very interested to expend my knowledge.

Comment: @MaximVeksler: There should be a lot of courses out there, I saw there are some related ones on coursera for example. I haven't done any personally however, most of my experience is from solving issues cropping up at work + answering some questions here on SO :)